# Multiple Selection Query MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to make a query which selects one record that has the player_type 'IF' and 10 records that has the player_type 'Gold' which is ordered by 'cardweight' field / rand() desc? Thanks. Below are some attached screenshots of my table showing of some the player_type 'IF' and 'Gold' records.

[Records with player_type as 'IF'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlwWT.png)

[Records with Player Type as 'Gold'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgVBe.png)

essentially, I would like to combine

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `my_players` 
WHERE  `player_type` =  'Gold'
ORDER BY cardweight / RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

and

```
    SELECT * 
FROM  `my_players` 
WHERE  `player_type` =  'IF'
ORDER BY cardweight / RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

in one query that can be ran at once if possible.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you're asking. Post some sample data and intended output

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I've tried to make it a bit clearer now sorry.

Comment: What are the fields that you want in each query output? are they same?

Comment: It should return all the information held in each record, but I just want it that it randomly selects 10 records with the player_type 'gold' and 1 with the record with the player type 'IF' and is selected randomly dependent on the cardweight field - e.g. ORDER BY cardweight/rand() desc

Comment: You should explain why the obvious solution of `union all` does or does not meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `union all`:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM  `my_players` 
WHERE  `player_type` =  'Gold'
ORDER BY cardweight / RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * 
FROM  `my_players` 
WHERE  `player_type` =  'IF'
ORDER BY cardweight / RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a UNION:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `my_players` 
WHERE  `player_type` =  'Gold'
ORDER BY cardweight / RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM  `my_players` 
WHERE  `player_type` =  'IF'
ORDER BY cardweight / RAND( ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```